Exterior Power and Action of Group (Reference)
Given the last answer of this post Fulton and Harris: Exercise 1.3 in section 1.1, it is asserted that if $v_1, ... v_n$ is a Basis for a Vector Space V, then a group (with representation) acts by $g(v_1 \wedge ... \wedge v_n) = det^n_{i,j}(g_{i,j}) v_1 \wedge ... \wedge v_n$. Could someone explain this?
I know that for $ w \in  \bigwedge\nolimits^kV*$ and a linear function $\phi: V \to V$ the determinant can be defined the following way $ \phi^*(ω) = ω(\phi(v)) = det(\phi)ω$. However hoes does $gv_i$ turn to a determiant ?

This is borderline the definition of the determinant.

It's not just any old group representation in the referenced question, it's one where all the $\rho(g)$ have determinant $1$. And then what @Chris says. And: have you a typo, shouldn't it be $det^{n}{i,j}(g{i,j})$?
